# How can I set static Egress IP for a pod?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks

Shortly, there are two services that communicates with each others via HTTP REST APIs. My deployment is running in an AKS cluster. For ingress controller, I installed this Nginx controller helm chart:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx 
The load balancer has a fix IP attached. My deployment running in my cluster should send usage info to the other service periodically and vica versa. However, that service has an IP whitelist and I need to provide a static IP for whitelisting my deployment. Currently, the problem is that my cURL call has the node's IP which is always changing depending on which node my deployment is running on. Also, the number of nodes are scaled dinamically, too. My goal is to send egress traffic through the loadbalancer something like this:
 [image] 
Is there any way to route the outbound traffic from my pods to the loadbalancer?

Comment: If I understand the question, you are looking for something like Istio MTLS sidecar https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/ that can intercept the inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: I am wondering if you add a rewrite rule in your nginx of Other service, and let Other service communicate with the nginx, will that work?

Comment: Technically the title of this question is incorrect as the pods are supposed to be dynamic, and the endpoint controller controls updating the IP address in the k8s service.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Azure Load Balancer with [outbound rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/egress-only); which the LB will do a SNAT and your "other service" will see the fixed frontend public IP. Another method is use [Virtual Network NAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/aks-nat-agic/aks-nat-agic/) where your "other service" will see the fixed NAT public IP. You can then whitelist the fixed public IP either way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the following link to update the load balancer to use the static egress/outbound IP address.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard